# How will having a link to libgcc_s.1.dylib from two sources break things?

Tags: macos, gcc, macports, dylib

I am building a binary with MacPorts GCC 4.7.2+universal on a Mac OS X 10.8.3 host running Xcode 4.6.2.

I am targeting the build for Mac OS X 10.5-10.8 hosts by using the compilation flag:

```
-mmacosx-version-min=10.5
```

The resulting binary `my_first_binary` has two links to `libgcc_s.1.dylib`:

```
$ otool -L ../bin/my_first_binary
../bin/my_first_binary:
    /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.17.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1669.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

The binary is written in C++, is compiled with the MacPorts `g++` 4.7.2+universal compiler and has some trouble opening up a file using some C I/O routines.

I make a second binary that targets 10.6-10.8 hosts by changing the compilation flag:

```
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6
```

This second binary has only one link to the `libgcc_s.1.dylib` library:

```
$ otool -L ../bin/my_second_binary
../bin/my_second_binary:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.17.0)
    /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

This second binary works properly and opens files without issues.

My questions are:

1. What about setting the minimum build version to 10.5 is causing the `/usr/lib`-variant of `libgcc_s.1.dylib` to be linked?
2. Can this cause namespace collisions or other problems with C-based code in my two binaries?
3. If this is a problem, what can I do to stop or troubleshoot this, while continuing to build to a minimum 10.5 target?